# How to disable Eslint in a Laravel project?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, eslint

I want to know how to disable or get rid off Eslint. I don't remember adding it with Vue in my Laravel project (8.x) but it just won't let me work.

```
    <template>
<h1 class="text-xl"> Here are our products! </h1>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    
}
</script>
```

The error is showing after `</script>` (no spaces).

[vue/comment-directive] clear eslint-plugin-vue